# How to delete a keyword and everything next to it in the databases by using sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have two table
1- the first insert everything but doesn't insert any words have a bantlon .
2- the second insert everything but doesn't insert any words have a shirt.

- note: when I insert the data maybe the words have more than one word, but I want to delete the basic word like (bantlon, shirt) and any word behind it.

  cr.execute("delete from shirt where mat like '%bantlon'")
  cr.execute("delete from banto where mat like '%shirt'")

Comment: You're better off doing that in python before inserting the strings. Sqlite string manipulate functions are pretty anemic.

Comment: Please show the table structure, and what records are problems. You can string manipulate with replace() and substr() For example: replace(mat, "banthlon", "") or substr(mat, instr(mat, "banthlon"))